# Galois groups of number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, anabelian-geometry

It seems that it is conjectured, that the absolute Galois group of a number field determines already the number field up to isomorphism.

I would like to know if there is a profinite group G such that only a unique number field has G as a Galois group.

Does the topology matter?

Comment: Your result in the first sentence is not a conjecture but rather a theorem, due to Neukirch and Uchida. See Minhyong's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23711/what-can-we-say-about-center-of-rational-absolute-galois-group

Comment: Finite Galois extensions of Q are examples where their absolute Galois group is not shared (up to isom. as profinite groups) by the absolute Galois group of any other number field. That's a consequence of the Neukirch--Uchida work and the fact that a finite Galois extension of Q is not isomorphic to any other number field but itself inside a fixed algebraic closure of Q.

Comment: The recent paper Class Field Theory as a Dynamical System, G. Cornellisen (http://arxiv.org/abs/1107.2159), has a short exposition on the matter, and shows some very exciting recent results.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by Conrad in the comments, your first statement is a theorem by Neukirch-Uchida (Neukirch-Ikeda-Iwasawa-Uchida, according to some sources).

Your second question is much more complicated, depending on how it is interpreted. As stated the answer is "yes, in fact infinitely many by Neukirch-Uchida".

But if you mean if we know a concrete profinite group $G$ such that $G\cong \mathrm{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ for some number field $K$, then the answer is "definitely no". But there are beautiful math behind this and related question, see for example the answers to [this question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/232930/profinite-groups-as-absolute-galois-groups).

I'm not sure what you mean by "does the topology matter". I don't think there is an alternative to using the Krull topology or something equivalent, if you want a working infinite Galois theory.